# Torque equilibrium of a cylinder

Tags: tensor-calculus, torque, equilibrium, stress-strain

In the process of deriving the stress tensor of a cube which is shown in the picture below, it is concluded from the torque equilibrium equation that $\sigma_{ij}$ is equal to $\sigma_{ji}$. I am trying to prove the same thing, but for a cylinder instead of a cube. Also, the cylinder is only under radial and longitudinal stress. This is why I am using cylindrical coordinates, but without the angle coordinate.

[image: Cube under stress]

In the picture below is the cylinder under stress. I assumed that on each surface there are stresses, unlike in the cube example where stresses are only defined at three of the six cube surfaces.

[image: Cylinder stress]

For the axis m which goes through the cylinders centroid in the radial direction, I wrote the following torque equilibrium equation:

$$ \sum{}M_Q=2\cdot\Big({dz\over2}\cdot2\pi (dr^2) \cdot \sigma_{zr}\Big)  - dr \cdot2\pi drdz\cdot\sigma_{rz}=0 =>\sigma_{zr}=\sigma_{rz} \tag{1}$$

From equation $(1)$ I conclueded that $\sigma_{rz}$ is equal to $\sigma_{zr}$. However, I am not sure if my way of coming to this conclusion is correct because I can not find any simular example online or in literature.

So my questions are:

1. Is my process of coming to the conclusion  $\sigma_{rz} = \sigma_{zr}$ correct?
2. If it is, why are cube stresses defined only at three of the six cube surfaces?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Same as $\sigma_{xy} = \sigma_{yx}$. Shear stresses need to matched in connected surfaces otherwise they will cause rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the cylinder is not an element of cylindrical coordinates. You cannot subdivide a solid with cylinders.

You need a cylindrical wedge, crudely drawn below

[image: fig1]

On this element, you place the stress components on its faces and do the force balance.

[image: fig2]

See [this article](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mechanical_Engineering/Structural_Mechanics_(Wierzbicki)/01%3A_The_Concept_of_Strain/1.03%3A_Description_of_Strain_in_the_Cylindrical_Coordinate_System) for the full definition of strain in cylindrical coordinates.

The stress tensor has a similar treatment to the strain tensor from above.

Comment: Hello John. Your answer helped guide me in the right direction. But I still do not understand one thing. For what point of the wedge should the torque equilibrium equation be written? Is it the one through which the axes $T_{RR}$ and $T_{ZZ}$ go through? If yes, why exactly that point? Is it because that point is the center of mass or something? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @NikolaRistic - Equilibrium should happen at ALL internal elemental volumes. This is how you develop how the stresses form for different locations.

Comment: Thank you very much John. This helped me :D